# Php POST form date to external website and setting session in external website?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to POST a form data to a external website. Lets say that I am doing validations in parent website (from where I am sending the data). Later on I want to manipulate FORM data in external website, interact with the DB there and I even want to set a session in external website. How can I do this?

Once form is submitted in the parent website, getting the date I want to creating a user in external website and want to set a user session in external website to auto log-in them.

Answer (score 1):

> Once form is submitted in the parent website, getting the date I want to creating a user in external website and want to set a user session in external website to auto log-in them.

Assuming that *external website* means "A website that is not under your control and is not partnering with you" then:

**You can't do this.**

The external website will almost certainly be using cookies to track users. While you could log in to it from PHP, there is no way that your site could tell the user's browser to store those cookies as if they came from the external site.

**You shouldn't do this.**

Creating accounts on websites usually involves:

- Accepting terms and conditions (you are unlikely to be in a legal position that would allow you to do on the user's behalf)
- Setting personal credentials such as passwords (which you, as a third party, should not have access to)

---

If, on the other hand, the external site *is* a partner or under your control then look at implementing [OAuth](http://oauth.net/).